# Running a C# application as 32-bit on a 64-bit machine

Tags: c#, .net, process, x86, 32bit-64bit

How do I force my application to run as 32-bit on a 64-bit machine?

The code is written in C#.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Right click your project, and select properties.

In properties, select the build tab. Under platform target, select x86.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save all files, right click the solution and select "Clean" to get rid of old binaries. Any builds after that should be 32 bit

Comment: This way it can only be run on x86 and cannot run on ARM or other architectures

Answer (score 12):

Command-line form:

```
corflags application.exe /32BIT+
```

(reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/corflags-exe-corflags-conversion-tool)

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I did it when we couldn't change the existing code from *Any CPU* to *x86* due to a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) limitation:

Create a 32-bit (x86 must be checked under project properties) 'launcher' application (Windows Application but not form):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Load the assembly    
    string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string assemblyName = Path.Combine(directory, "YourAnyCPUApplication.exe");
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyName);
    assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Add the following code to the Main method in the *Any CPU* project:

```
if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    // etc...
}
else
{
    // Launch application in 32-bit mode
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
                                     + @"\Your32BitApplicationLauncher.exe");
}
```

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you go to Configuration Manager in Visual Studio you can set the platform to x86 or x64.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a Winforms, console app, or Windows service you have to build the exe for x86 instead of Any CPU. It's in the Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the project to x86 will prevent the file from executing on non-x86 platforms such as ARM. Since Visual Studio 11 and .NET framwork 4.5 there's a new option named [`Any CPU 32-bit preferred`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13149905/995714) and this was the default since then. The resulting code will run on *any* platforms but on 64-bit platforms they are run as 32-bit processes

## Further reading

- [What is the purpose of the "Prefer 32-bit" setting in Visual Studio and how does it actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12066638/995714)
- [What does the "Prefer 32-bit" compiler flag mean for Visual Studio (C#, VB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7508965/995714)
- [What AnyCPU Really Means As Of .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 11](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/)