# How we run a .NET 32-bit application in a 64-bit Windows server?

Tags: .net, web-applications, .net-2.0

We are installing a third party application in one of our 64-bit Windows servers.  This application apparently was build with the compiler option set to choose the platform at run time.  When we run the application it gives us an error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have seen in MSDN forums that in order to fix this error I have to build the application set to 32-bit, and that way it will run fine on a 64-bit server.  I check on other StackOverflow links [Other Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437271/running-c-app-32-bit-on-64-bit-machine).

How to get around this situation?  For everyone that wants to know more information:

1. The application is running fine in a 32-bit test server.
2. IIS version 6
3. using SQL Server Express 2005
4. On the Web Service Extension there are both Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
5. and Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is that the application depends on an unmanaged DLL that needs to be run in 32-bit mode.  Since the default "AnyCPU" .NET build checks the platform automatically the .NET part of the program is starting in 64-bit mode.  This will cause the calls to the 32-bit-only unmanaged DLL to fail.

To fix it, you need to create a manifest file to tell the app to run in 32-bit mode.  I've never needed to do that myself, so I can't provide instructions and a quick Google search hasn't (yet) turned up anything.

[Update]
See if this link helps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191.aspx

Comment: The manifest are not present in the wwwroot folder.  Maybe for security purposes.  Maybe I cannot find them.

Comment: There may not be any manifest yet- you may have to create it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this will help, but check it out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score -1):

The details of the question is a little confusing but I'll take a punt.

You need to the version aspnet_regiis.exe found in the Framework\v2.0.50727\ folder against the web site where this code is running

Answer (score -1):

One thing that might work is making sure the .Net application is flagged as a true 32 bit application by changing the target CPU details.

In the *Visual Studio 2005* you can do this by going to the project *Properties* and in the *Build* section set the *Platform Target* to *x86* and not *Any APU* which is the default.

Comment: This does not help when it is a third-party application - it can't be built with Visual Studio.