# What does the "Prefer 32-bit" compiler flag mean for Visual Studio (C#, VB)?

Tags: c#, vb.net, compiler-flags, visual-studio-2012

Just got the Visual Studio 11 developer preview installed. I see a new option in the project properties called "Prefer 32-bit" when compiling a managed (C#, VB) application with the AnyCPU target specified. This doesn't appear to be an option for class libraries, just top-level apps.

What does this flag indicate?

Comment: You should refer to this post, http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the "Prefer 32-bit" setting in Visual Studio and how does it actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066638/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-prefer-32-bit-setting-in-visual-studio-and-how-does)

Comment: @DaveInCaz: How it can be a duplicate of a newer question?

Comment: @IvanH according to StackOverflow guidance, "The general rule is to keep the question with the best collection of answers" https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It likely indicates the app is AnyCpu but when 32 bit is available it shouold run as such. This makes sense - 64 bit apps use more memory, and sometimes you just dont need the memory space ;)

Comment: 64bit apps also cannot be debugged with edit and continue. Setting "Prefer 32-bit" hopefully enabled x64 users to debug the applications running on AnyCPU again without setting the target to x86/32bit compile.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Please refer to http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11.aspx

Comment: Then why not post it as answer ;-)

Comment: @LexLi is correct, this answer is wrong, from the article they linked, "If the process runs on a 64-bit Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit process. IL is compiled to x86 machine code.",  "The difference, then, between “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” and “x86” is only this: a .NET application compiled to x86 will fail to run on an ARM Windows system, but an “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” application will run successfully."

Comment: [Archive.org Link for now dead Microsoft article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120406144909/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
Application compiled with "Any CPU 32-bit preferred" is compatible with x86, x64 and ARM, while x86 is compatible only with x86, x64 and not ARM. For details see [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/).

Comment: That's not what the article says. Read again: `a .NET application compiled to x86 will fail to run on an ARM Windows system, but an “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” application will run successfully.`

Answer (score 2):

Here's right and simple answer:

[image: Application arch.]

Answer (score 1):

There is an good article at [What AnyCPU Really Means As Of .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 11](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/).

The short answer to your question is "When using that flavor of AnyCPU, the semantics are the following:

If the process runs on a 32-bit Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit process. IL is compiled to x86 machine code.
If the process runs on a 64-bit Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit process. IL is compiled to x86 machine code.
If the process runs on an ARM Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit process. IL is compiled to ARM machine code.
The difference, then, between “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” and “x86” is only this: a .NET application compiled to x86 will fail to run on an ARM Windows system, but an “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” application will run successfully."

Comment: The content of your answer is correct, but I'm curious, why did you remove the nice bullet list formatting present in the original article?