# Turn off "Prefer 32-bit" build will stop application from launching

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-studio-2012, build

My application is VS2012 WPF application. If I turn off "Prefer 32-bit" build, my application will not launch (a window pop up saying error while trying to run.....).

If I want my application to launch, I have to turn on "Prefer 32-bit" option.

My machine is 64-bit Windows 7. I want my application to be 64-bit because I need to load a 64-bit native dll.

What should I do with this case? Why turning off "Prefer 32-bit" build will stop application from launching?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error in the pop up?

Comment: error while trying to run "C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe". To me, it looks like it does not really say anything.

Comment: Similar errors I've seen related to assemblies being loaded that are actually still 32 bit, or vice versa.

Comment: See if this related question helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/13149905/3747990

Comment: I cannot think any 32bit dll gets loaded into my application.

Comment: It will be a bit of an effort, but `CorFlags` can help double check the assemblies and `Dependency Walker` for any native stuff.

Comment: If I log off, the first time the application will run. Afterwards it will not.

Comment: In addition, for the first time the error occur, it actually shows "the network location cannot be reached". Then this information will longer showing afterwards.

Comment: There seems to be a lot going on in the background here, I'm not sure if I'll be able to help here.

Comment: No worries, appreciate you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dependency walker. You need to make sure your references are all 32-bit or all 64-bit.