# Compiling 32bit app on 64bit machine

Tags: asp.net, 32bit-64bit

I want to convert my 32bit application to 64bit so I could compile it and keep working on it on my 64bit machine. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

To compile at 64bit:

Inside Visual Studio go to **Build > Configuration Manager**

[image]

Then you can specify CPU by selecting the Platform column and choosing between X86 and x64.

[image]

Then you can explicitly compile at 64bit.

---

That said [*Any CPU*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/what-does-the-visual-studio-any-cpu-target-mean) should be good enough for you to keep working on it. My carry around is 64bit, but the buildserver can output the projects as either 32bit or 64bit depenedent on the release template.

---

Also dependent on your Visual Studio version, there is the [Prefer 32bit flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508965/what-does-the-prefer-32-bit-compiler-flag-mean-for-visual-studio-11-managed-ap) which may be of use dependent on your exact requirements.