# F# build 32-bit executable from command line

Tags: f#

I need to run an F# program from another 32-bit executable. I don't have any access to source code of this one. How do I build 32-bit F# executable file under 64-bit OS from command line?

Comment: Set the output to x86 instead of "Any"?

Comment: @crashmstr Thank you much, I managed to find a solution on SO. Forgot that C# is compiled to the same kind of binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've finally found an answer just after I asked the question on SO. (This somehow helps, you know). The answer is here:

[Running a 32-bit C# application on a 64-bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437271/running-a-32-bit-c-sharp-application-on-a-64-bit-machine)

You need to run `corflags /32BIT+` situated at `\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\corflags.exe`, so that the executable runs with 32bit on 64bit OS.